# Digital World Clock SharePoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I am looking to create a web part that displays the current time in different areas around the world (preset) preferably adjusting to day light savings time. Ive looked at a couple webparts and they are all in a different format to the one I am looking for.

Format :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
   London - Mon 8:10AM      Hong Kong - Mon 2:10PM     New York - Mon 2:10AM   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to include this above or below a site banner as a seperate web part.Would it be possible to pull the time from a site like timeanddate.com or similiar?

Any help in either modifying an existing web part or creating a new webpart would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have created world clocks in SharePoint before.  I had to use an ASMX web service with JQuery to get the different time zones and daylight savings time differences.  Look into web services.

Comment: @lazoDev Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a world clock in SharePoint using Javascript with the [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) libraries. The benefit to this approach is that you don't need to call an external service. The downside is that it relies upon the time on the client. I wasn't building an atomic clock so it was suitable for my needs.

Here is an example that targets a DIV with the ID `currentTime`. In my implementation, the visitors clicks on a link to see the time in that region. The variable `currentRegion` matches a [Moment Timezone Zone object](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/) and can be changed by clicking on a link (that code is not included).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(showTime, 1000);
});

function showTime() {
    var cT = moment().tz(currentRegion).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss A');
    $('#currentTime').text("Current Time: " + cT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution for your case here :
http://sharepointhero.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/adding-world-clock-and-exchange-rates-web-parts-to-sharepoint/

Comment: Can you add some context about your link? Link only answers can be troublesome if the link breaks.